# I'm trying to make a slideshow with the same title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to put more images to that code in order to make it a slideshow, but keeping the h1 and h2 tags there, even when the images are sliding
Here is the code I have which properly shows the image with the titles on top of it: 
HTML:

```
<header class="header-image">
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>SanDesigns</h1>
            <h2>The RENDERS you are looking for</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header-image {
display:block;
width:100%;
background:url(Matthias_Leuzinger_test_Test_exterior_BB_View01_.jpg)  no-repeat;
min-height:605px;
margin-top:-1px; 
}

.title {
padding-left: 15%;
padding-top:5%;
font-family:GeosansLight;
}

.title h1 {
width: 18.75%;
border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
background-color:#7A7A7A;
text-align:center;
color:#FFF7F7;
}

.title h2 {
border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
background-color:#7A7A7A;
text-align:center;
width:30%;
color:#FFF7F7;
}
```

Ok, there is this other code that in which I was able to do the slideshow, but in this one I can put the divs with the h1 and h2 tags:

```
<nav class="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#diseños">Diseños</a></li>
    <li><a href="#articulos">Articulos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#equipo">Equipo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<header class="slideshow">
<img class="header-image" src="Architectural-Photorealistic-3D-Renders.jpg">
<img class="header-image" src="Channel-Place-Residence_LA.jpg">
<img class="header-image" src="Matthias_Leuzinger_test_Test_exterior_BB_View01_.jpg">
<img class="header-image" src="p2010018-20110510-view1-modepark.jpg">
</header>
```

And the script:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("header-image");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(carousel, 6000); // Change image every 6 seconds
```

}

Comment: Can you post your HTML and JS code, plus if you are using any other resources such as jQuery plugin, etc.

Comment: <body>
<nav class="navbar">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#diseños">Diseños</a></li>
        <li><a href="#articulos">Articulos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#equipo">Equipo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<header class="header-image">
 <div class="headline">
     <div class="title">
      <h1>SanDesigns</h1>
         <h2>The RENDERS you are looking for</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</body>

Comment: And I found on the w3c this script:
I found on the w3c this script:
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("header-image");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(carousel, 6000); // Change image every 6 seconds
}
</script>
</html>

Comment: Please edit that into your question

Comment: @AndresSanchez it's better for us if you provide your code with the proper structure, and if you can to give us a better approach of your issue please add a jsfiddle with the problem so we can debug in there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pLjtwn7h/
That is the code that does the slideshow, but now I want to add to that code the h1 and h2 tags in a way that when the images slide the tags stay there. Is there a way to make this possible. 
I'm sorry for not making it easy, it is my first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a javascript that change your background, but you need to add an id to your  header div:

HTML

```
<header class="header-image" id="changingHeader">
    <div class="headline">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>SanDesigns</h1>
            <h2>The RENDERS you are looking for</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script language="javascript">
var currentImg = 1;
function changeBg(imgNumber){

var images = ['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg','img4.jpg','img5.jpg']

document.getElementById('changingHeader').style.backgroundImage = "url("+images[imgNumber]+")";
if (currentImg <= 3){
      currentImg ++;
}else{
currentImg = 0;
}

}
setInterval(function(){
    changeBg(currentImg);
}, 5000);  // this will run every 5 seconds
</script>
```

CSS

```
.header-image {
display:block;
width:100%;
background:url(img1.jpg)  no-repeat;
min-height:605px;
margin-top:-1px; 
}

.title {
padding-left: 15%;
padding-top:5%;
font-family:GeosansLight;
}

.title h1 {
width: 18.75%;
border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
background-color:#7A7A7A;
text-align:center;
color:#FFF7F7;
}

.title h2 {
border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
background-color:#7A7A7A;
text-align:center;
width:30%;
color:#FFF7F7;
}
```

Comment: I did that, but my dreamweaver says there is an error on line 5, with the var images = new array...

Comment: Does anyone know what is wrong with that JavaScript code? I did everything as Astolfo Vesci wrote, but dreamweaver keeps saying the: "syntax error on line 6. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error"

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

---

```
<h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:800px;position:relative">

<img class="mySlides" src="img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides" src="img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">

<a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;left:0" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="w3-btn-floating" style="position:absolute;top:45%;right:0" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a>

</div>
```

Please check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self